# Does setVisibility(View.GONE) pauses drawing?

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to android and noticed something really weird(if my theory isn't true), I have this kind of layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I noticed a behavior that got me thinking if when you call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` it pause the drawing(animating) of the view, here is the course of actions:

```
swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Show container
swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true); // Loader is shown
//->And now few seconds it the future after data loaded...`
swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false); // Loader dismiss animation starts..., spinner diameter starts to get smaller(the dismiss animation) but pauses with a very small diameter.
swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Here is where I think the drawing pauses.
//-> Few seconds later...
swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // The very small diameter spinner is shown and continue to get smaller until the animation ends.
```

I have no other explanation to what I see, I've taken a huge amount of time to think about it and basically what I'm asking to know is that: Is android pauses the view drawing when calling `setVisibility(View.GONE)`?

**Update:**

Thanks to @Nordenheim I also checked `swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` but still, same behavior, so I checked with `swipeContainer.setAlpha(0f);` and now the problem is gone, but the question still stand about `setVisibility(View.GONE)`, I just want confirmation/denial.

Comment: Does it still pause if you call `swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` instead of `swipeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: @Nordenheim still, same.